# Why does the Arduino delay receiving data from Visual Basic.NET?

Tags: vb.net, arduino, arduino-uno

This is the Arduino code for the receiver

```
void loop() {
  
  int dir = Serial.read();
  if (dir == 'A') {
    Motors();
  }

  if (dir == 'B') {
    Zero();
  }

}
```

and this Visual Basic.NET Code

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If Button1.Enabled = True Then
            SerialPort1.Open()
            SerialPort1.Write("A")
            SerialPort1.Write(txtAngle1Mr.Text + Chr(13))
            SerialPort1.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
```

okay when I click on the button , my program write "A" ON SERIAL
And if write "A" ON SERIAL
Arduino Will Run "Motors" Function

Arduino is Delaying to receive data from Visual Basic.NET and run "Motors" Function

Arduino runs "Motors" Function. but he's Delaying

why Arduino is Delaying  ?
and how can I solve this ?

Comment: There is no need to check if Button1 is enabled since Button1 won't raise the Click event if it is not enabled.

Comment: Uno resets on new USB connection

Comment: @Juraj How can I Uno resets on new USB connection –

Comment: You are opening the port for every button click. Open the connection at the start ofthe program and use the button just to send the data.

Comment: Hi everyone. 
I solved the problem. 
look to my reply on my question .

Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem

In VisualBasic.NET I was sending one value by just 1 code.

```
SerialPort1.Write(TextBox1.Text + Chr(13))
```

and in Arduino I was receving the data by just one code

```
int example 1 = Serial.parseInt();
```

the problem is

in arduino I was receving more than value and I just send one value!
I was receiving data that I did not send!

in VisualBasic I wrote this

```
SerialPort1.Write(TextBox1.Text + Chr(13))
```

in Arduino I wrote this

```
int example1 = Serial.parseInt();
int example2 = Serial.parseInt();
int example3 = Serial.parseInt();
int example4 = Serial.parseInt();
```

look. I was sending one value and the arduino was trying to receive more than one value

This is why the Arduino was late in receiving data

I hope you understand me

Thank you all